# goutte returns The current node list is empty

Tags: php, web-crawler, goutte

The code below always returns `The current node list is empty.`

```php
 $c = $client->request('GET', 'https://mihanblockchain.com/exchange-prices');

    $selector = "[data-coin|='usdt'] tr td#ex-1-buy-price";

    $result = $c->filter($selector)->text();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if `$c` actually contains the HTML of the page with a `var_dump` ? Most probably the server hosting the website you're scraping is blocking your requests.

Comment: yes it does, I've just checked that and the HTML exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your last selector is `#ex-1-buy-price`, which is an unique ID in the page, you don't need everything else

```
$selector = "#ex-1-buy-price";
$result = $c->filter($selector)->text();
```

This works and returns `840,000,100 تومان`